# Should a Repository throw an exception if no change is to be stored?

Tags: oop, exception, repository, domain-driven-design, design-by-contract

During the stipulation of the contracts of my Repositories I started to wonder about an essential contract of any `Repository`:
**What happens if `Update` is called with a an entity on which no change is to be stored?**

1. As a client of the `Repository` I would only call `Update` if I wanted to store a change. If there is no change, I would assume something went wrong inside my process so I want to be informed about this fact.

So I'd say: **An uncommitted change is a precondition of the `Update` method.**
This entails **throwing an `Exception`** if this precondition is not met.

2. But here is another view: **The `Repository` is indifferent to change**. The `Update` method just ensures that a given entity is persisted as it now is. **If there was a change at all is not the `Repository's` business.** So no Exception.

Personally, I tend to view 1 since the term `Update` itself suggests that a change happened.

What is your opinion to this topic?

---

PS: Let's suppose (for the sake of the example) that there is no concurrency involved which of course would lead to other possible outcomes.

Comment: Are you rolling your own change tracking module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens if Update is called with a an entity on which no change is to be stored?

I think you want that to be a no-op.

The usual pattern for working with a persistence backed repository [looks something like](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/application/impl/BookingServiceImpl.java#L66)

```
final Cargo cargo = cargoRepository.find(trackingId);
cargo.assignToRoute(itinerary);
cargoRepository.store(cargo);
```

This code lives in the application component; the repository and the Cargo aggregate root are the abstractions that the domain model is allowed to know about.  The details of the implementation are *somewhere else*.

Riddle: what happens if `cargo.assignToRoute` is, for the current state, a no-op?  The *application* can't know this, because it doesn't have access to the underlying state.  It invoked the model, the model decided not to change anything, and so the repository finds the same state that is available in storage.

This can matter because, if your messages are coming to you over unreliable transport (like the web), you might get two copies of the *same message*.  If the domain model recognizes that the new itinerary is equal to the old one, it doesn't need to change anything.

```
final Cargo cargo = cargoRepository.find(trackingId);
cargo.assignToRoute(itinerary);
cargoRepository.store(cargo);
final Cargo cargo = cargoRepository.find(trackingId);
cargo.assignToRoute(itinerary);
cargoRepository.store(cargo);
```

Is introducing an exception in this flow actually delivering business value? or are we just inventing extra work for ourselves?

Are we really putting in a bunch of extra scaffolding to detect the following, harmless, code *at runtime*?

```
final Cargo cargo = cargoRepository.find(trackingId);
cargoRepository.store(cargo);
```

A way of *thinking* about the mechanics here: we don't call the model to make it *do* anything.  We call the domain model because we want a particular [post condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondition) to be satisfied.  If the model *already* satisfies that post condition, then there's no change to make.

This pattern is typical of [idempotent receivers](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/IdempotentReceiver.html); for example, the [HTTP PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) method is reserved for operations that promise [idempotent semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2).

(More precisely, you are proposing a [precondition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition) -- that the caller ensure that the two states are different -- that must be satisfied to invoke the method.  But in this case the precondition is a phantom; the method *could* satisfy the post condition, it just chooses not too.)

Comment: Agreed.  When retrieving data I may, at times, have both a `Get()` *and* a `Find()` method where `Find()` may return `null` but `Get()` would throw and exception when no item is located.  Storing data, on the other hand, is slightly different and I buy the idempotence point 100%.  In the above example any *real* exception/invariant would probably better be applied in the `assignToRoute()` method.  A repository is probably not the best place to implement rules.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, which gave me the final hint I needed, especially the idempotency! Also see the answer of @guillaume31 which I think lets the question be superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely sure that the uncommitted change is a precondition then you have a reason for something to throw an exception if that precondition has not been met.
If this is a precondition, you rule out non-exceptional calling of update in cases where there might be changes or there might not be. If that's what you want then OK.

However, as you hint at with your point 2, its not really the repository that's done anything exceptional.

You could consider a separate check for whether there are any uncommitted changes prior to update in those cases where you really expect changes.

This is quite like the question of whether file delete should throw if the file does not exist before deleting. In some use cases I'm really expecting that file to be there, so it would be exceptional if it didn't, however another use case is where I want to make sure the file doesn't exist, but I don't know (or care) whether it currently exists. In that case, if I consider the post condition "the specified file does not exist after the call to delete" then (unless the file exists and is undeletable) that has been met whether the file existed before or not.

The update post-condition is that there are no uncommitted changes after the call, this is met for both the successful update and the nothing-to-update cases.

Having to catch exceptions in these non-exceptional cases where the post-condition has been met is annoying. The intent of the code would be clearer if there was an option or a different method that can differentiate between the cases where the precondition should or shouldn't apply, this could be more efficient/easier than checking the precondition separately.

Answer (score 1):

*Don't include `Update` in your Repository interface.*

A Repository is an illusion of an in-memory collection (quoting the blue book from memory here). `Update(element)` doesn't exist in collection semantics.

Instead, handle change tracking in your Unit of Work implementation. Most ORM's have optimized, built-in change tracking you can conveniently use for that purpose.

Comment: Yes, you're right. After thinking about this for some time, I really appreciate this reminder! I was aware of the fact that the Repository is an illusion of an in-memory collection but now I really understand why this is so important.